# Installing snapd on 14.04 fails

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, snap

I have a virtual server running 14.04, hosted by Host Europe. I want to install Nextcloud using `snap`. However, installing `snapd` fails:

```
$ sudo apt install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cgroup-lite crda dmsetup grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc
  grub-pc-bin grub2-common iw libcryptsetup4 libdevmapper1.02.1 libfuse2
  libsystemd-journal0 linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-headers-4.4.0-112
  linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial
  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial squashfs-tools systemd thermald
  wireless-regdb
Suggested packages:
  multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base console-setup fuse fdutils
  linux-lts-xenial-tools systemd-ui
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cgroup-lite crda dmsetup grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc
  grub-pc-bin grub2-common iw libcryptsetup4 libdevmapper1.02.1 libfuse2
  libsystemd-journal0 linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-headers-4.4.0-112
  linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial
  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial snapd squashfs-tools systemd thermald
  wireless-regdb
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 85.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 408 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main dmsetup amd64 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 [37.6 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main libdevmapper1.02.1 amd64 2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2 [93.3 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main libfuse2 amd64 2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1 [87.4 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main libsystemd-journal0 amd64 204-5ubuntu20.26 [51.0 kB]
Get:5 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main wireless-regdb all 2013.02.13-1ubuntu1 [6456 B]
Get:6 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main crda amd64 1.1.2-1ubuntu2 [15.2 kB]
Get:7 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main grub-common amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14 [1679 kB]
Get:8 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main grub2-common amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14 [501 kB]
Get:9 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main grub-pc-bin amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14 [882 kB]
Get:10 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main grub-pc amd64 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14 [174 kB]
Get:11 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main grub-gfxpayload-lists amd64 0.6 [3506 B]
Get:12 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main iw amd64 3.4-1 [51.7 kB]
Get:13 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main libcryptsetup4 amd64 2:1.6.1-1ubuntu1 [77.0 kB]
Get:14 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic amd64 4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1 [20.9 MB]
Get:15 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic amd64 4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1 [35.7 MB]
Get:16 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-image-generic-lts-xenial amd64 4.4.0.112.96 [2516 B]
Get:17 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-headers-4.4.0-112 all 4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1 [9923 kB]
Get:18 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic amd64 4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1 [773 kB]
Get:19 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial amd64 4.4.0.112.96 [2486 B]
Get:20 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main linux-generic-lts-xenial amd64 4.4.0.112.96 [1800 B]
Get:21 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty/main cgroup-lite all 1.9 [3918 B]
Get:22 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main squashfs-tools amd64 1:4.2+20130409-2ubuntu0.14.04.2 [90.6 kB]
Get:23 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security/main systemd amd64 204-5ubuntu20.26 [1425 kB]
Get:24 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/universe snapd amd64 2.29.4.2~14.04 [13.0 MB]
Get:25 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates/main thermald amd64 1.4.3-5~14.04.4 [202 kB]
Fetched 85.7 MB in 7s (11.4 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package dmsetup.
(Reading database ... 146702 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dmsetup_2%3a1.02.77-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dmsetup (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libdevmapper1.02.1_2%3a1.02.77-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfuse2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfuse2_2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfuse2:amd64 (2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsystemd-journal0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd-journal0_204-5ubuntu20.26_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd-journal0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.26) ...
Selecting previously unselected package wireless-regdb.
Preparing to unpack .../wireless-regdb_2013.02.13-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking wireless-regdb (2013.02.13-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package crda.
Preparing to unpack .../crda_1.1.2-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking crda (1.1.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grub-common.
Preparing to unpack .../grub-common_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grub2-common.
Preparing to unpack .../grub2-common_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub2-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grub-pc-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../grub-pc-bin_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grub-pc.
Preparing to unpack .../grub-pc_2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Selecting previously unselected package grub-gfxpayload-lists.
Preparing to unpack .../grub-gfxpayload-lists_0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package iw.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/iw_3.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking iw (3.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcryptsetup4.
Preparing to unpack .../libcryptsetup4_2%3a1.6.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcryptsetup4 (2:1.6.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic-lts-xenial_4.4.0.112.96_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.112.96) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-112.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-112_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-112 (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic_4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial_4.4.0.112.96_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.112.96) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic-lts-xenial.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic-lts-xenial_4.4.0.112.96_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.112.96) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cgroup-lite.
Preparing to unpack .../cgroup-lite_1.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking cgroup-lite (1.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package squashfs-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../squashfs-tools_1%3a4.2+20130409-2ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking squashfs-tools (1:4.2+20130409-2ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package systemd.
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_204-5ubuntu20.26_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (204-5ubuntu20.26) ...
Selecting previously unselected package snapd.
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.29.4.2~14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.29.4.2~14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package thermald.
Preparing to unpack .../thermald_1.4.3-5~14.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thermald (1.4.3-5~14.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Setting up libfuse2:amd64 (2.9.2-4ubuntu4.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libsystemd-journal0:amd64 (204-5ubuntu20.26) ...
Setting up wireless-regdb (2013.02.13-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up crda (1.1.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up iw (3.4-1) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-112-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-112 (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial (4.4.0.112.96) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (= 4.4.0.112.96); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cgroup-lite (1.9) ...
cgroup-lite start/running
Setting up squashfs-tools (1:4.2+20130409-2ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on linux-generic-lts-xenial; however:
  Package linux-generic-lts-xenial is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up thermald (1.4.3-5~14.04.4) ...
thermald start/running, process 10038
Setting up libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14) ...
Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.6) ...
Setting up libcryptsetup4 (2:1.6.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up systemd (204-5ubuntu20.26) ...
systemd start/running, process 10241
Setting up dmsetup (2:1.02.77-6ubuntu2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.14) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-generic-lts-xenial
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to run `snap` leads to an error:

```
 $ sudo snap install hello-world
 error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/hello-world: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I already tried to install `snapd` before. The packages listed at the end of the installation procedure

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-generic-lts-xenial
 snapd
```

cause all further attempts to run `sudo apt upgrade -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fail. I had to use `sudo dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq PACKAGE_NAME` to remove these packages. Even then, I couldn't get rid of `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic`, so I had to manually remove it from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

The kernel I am currently running:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-042stab127.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just told by the hosting company that using `snapd` on the hosted virtual server is impossible, because of the container virtualization that is being used. The container of the virtual server shares the kernel of the host system. Therefore, upgrading the kernel or using another kernel is not possible.

Comment: Don't use container-virtualization VPSes.  You need fully virtualized virtual servers for snaps and such to work.  Just an FYI for the future :)

Comment: Yeah, I will second what Thomas has said above. The poster child of those VPSes are running ancient kernels that allow them to get greater density through a zoo of patches that are not mainlined. It's nice on paper but probably has unpatched security issues simply because they don't track any supported kernel tree. Just say no and buy a real VM.

Answer (score 1):

Just reboot. You got a new kernel (a prerequisite for snapd) but you are not running it yet. After reboot everything should work OK.

Comment: The kernel he _was_ running is not an official one. I expect if he reboots it will all go wrong.

Comment: Rebooting did not change anything. I am still running the same kernel.

Comment: This worked for me for Ubuntu 14.04 running in DigitalOcean.